# How should I search for IP conflicts in static networks?

Tags: windows, networking, ip

We have two physically separate static networks with the same subnet, containing a total of some ~100 windows computers (servers and workstations) that we want to merge. If configuration is done correctly, there should be no ip conflicts, but we experience some weird behavior in the network when simply connecting them (some servers seem to be dropping in and out). We want to check if there is an IP conflict. What is the best way to forge ahead?

Comment: Get a DHCP server, configure everything you possibly can to obtain addresses from DHCP. Configure all devices that have to have static IPs with DHCP reservations and, if possible, configure the device to pull its IP address from DHCP. It's 2014. Nobody should be using static IP addresses on any host where it isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: There is dinosaur software running on these servers, which is configured by static ip's. Anyways, it is not my decision.

Comment: DHCP reservations can be used to mimic assigning static IP addresses to hosts and lets you centrally manage IP allocation.

Comment: I will certainly keep that in mind while planning future projects. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation tells that you have no clue of IP addressing scheme in that particular setup.
If so, I would simply check all servers and their IP, after do simple ip scan, you can google it or faster way is check arp tables on servers on both networks.

Comment: arp -a in the command prompt was what I was looking for :-)